# Convertig latex to docx using pandoc

Tags: listings, itemize, pandoc, msword

as a latex newbie I converted latex file via pandoc to docx. Itemized list with items a), b), etc. appears correctly in pdf but in docx it appears as bullet list. I tried different workarounds but with no success.

I used miktex distribution, texmaker as editor:

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[german]{babel}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage[left=2cm,right=2cm,top=2cm,bottom=2cm]{geometry}
\begin{document}
\textbf{examples:} \\ \\

\textbf{List using ``itemize''}
\begin{itemize}
\item[a) ]Item 1
\item[b) ]Item 2
\item[c) ]Item 3\\
\end{itemize}

\textbf{List using ``enumerate''}
\renewcommand{\labelenumi}{\alph{enumi}) }
\begin{enumerate}
\item Item 1 
\item Item 2
\item Item 3
\end{enumerate}

\end{document}
```

===================

pandoc command line:

```
pandoc -f latex -t docx -i test.tex -o test.docx
```

PDF looks like expected:

[image: pdf]

DOCX does not:

[image: docx]

Any help much appreciated!

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: `pandoc` generally ignores detailed options, so unless you do something very clever with your template files, it just won't see those optional labels you have in the first list, or the `renewcommand` that you have put before the second list.

Comment: To add to Thruston's comment: Pandoc also ignores `enumitem` settings.

Comment: You may have a look to pandoc's `--reference-doc` option.

Comment: You may also ask pandoc's forum: https://groups.google.com/g/pandoc-discuss